# How can I build a histogram with factor intervals?

Tags: r, histogram

I need to build a histogram out of some factors, but those factors describe number intervals, for example, the intervals 0-2000, 2000-4000, 4000-6000, 6000-8000, 8000-10000 and i know in what frequence itens falls into those intervals, how would i do it?

I've tried turning the intervals into numbers but, didn't really arrived at anywhere.

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(mydata)` as part of your question.

Comment: Look up the `?cut` function...

Comment: That is a barplot and not a histogram. Histogram is for continuous variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is how to convert factors of numbers into something number-like so that you can plot a histogram on it.

```r
quux <- data.frame(x = factor(c("0-2000", "2000-4000", "4000-6000", "6000-8000", "8000-10000")))
quux
#            x
# 1     0-2000
# 2  2000-4000
# 3  4000-6000
# 4  6000-8000
# 5 8000-10000
```

I think the easiest start is to come up with two values for each string, each a value.

```r
nums <- lapply(strsplit(levels(quux$x), "[^0-9]+"), as.numeric)
str(nums)
# List of 5
#  $ : num [1:2] 0 2000
#  $ : num [1:2] 2000 4000
#  $ : num [1:2] 4000 6000
#  $ : num [1:2] 6000 8000
#  $ : num [1:2] 8000 10000
```

You can convert this into whatever "numbers" you want each to represent. Examples:

```r
### first of each pair
sapply(nums, `[[`, 1)
# [1]    0 2000 4000 6000 8000

### min, different from above if they are not always in order;
### this time showing addition of the 'na.rm=TRUE' in case 
### there are non-numbers
sapply(nums, min, na.rm = TRUE)
# [1]    0 2000 4000 6000 8000

### average of each pair
sapply(nums, mean)
# [1] 1000 3000 5000 7000 9000
```

Whichever you choose, you can then place that value into whatever hist-plotting expression you're planning to use.